# Hide Superfish menu on selected pages

Tags: theming, navigation

I have installed Danland Theme and it is cool. I want the superfish menu to be appeared on few pages, not all the pages. For example if I type a wrong URL address in the address bar, it says Page not found and it still gives that Superfish menu there on the page.

[image: This page doesn't exist]

I have some pages, where I don't want that superfish menu to be appeared.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto /admin/structure/block/ configure your superfish menu block

Scroll down to the bottom and locate "Show block on specific pages"

select this option " Only the listed pages "

and define the paths of the pages on which you want superfish menu to appear.